# ADB Sideload is stuck, can I flash zip manually instead?

Tags: rooting, twrp, side-loading, supersu

I'm trying to root my phone. I managed to unlock bootloader and flash TWRP. Next thing guide says is to boot into TWRP (which I managed too) and then enable sideload and flash SuperSU via `adb sideload file.zip` command. This is where TWRP gets stuck at *Starting ADB sideload feature...* ḿessage.
Do you have any tips how to make this work, or can I flash SuperSU via TWRP without sideload?

TWRP version: twrp-3.0.2-0-a16

Comment: What phone is this for?  You should just be able to flash SuperSU's zip instead of using adb sideload.

Comment: HTC Desire 530. OK I will try, but I guess I should make a full backup before I try installing SuperSU, should i?

Comment: Yeah, that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. In fact, ADB isn't at all necessary.

First of all, to save you a lot of worries, I will inform you about [FlashFire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.flash). It's easily the best way to install ROMs and other such things if you do have root. Download it if you have root.

If you don't have root, here's the non-root TWRP method To boot into TWRP differs from phone to phone, so I won't go into it here. I will, however, detail the rest of the process. Make sure the ROM's ZIP file is on the phone.

1. **Make a Nandroid backup (optional):** You should back your phone up in case something goes higgledy piggledy. Go to Backup and choose what partitions to save.
2. **Wipe The Phone** Go back to the TWRP homescreen, select Wipe and then swipe the bar. Your phone (but not it's internal storage) will be completely reset.
3. **Install the ROM:** Go back to the TWRP homescreen and select Install. Navigate to your ROM's zip file and select it. Swipe the bar to begin installing.
4. If you have a Google Apps zip, repeat Step 3 with it.
5. Reboot your phone.

That's basically how. Phones can be a bit slow on startup for the first time after the flash, but you should be fine. If something does go wrong, install from your Nandroid backup.

Comment: Additional warning to OP: since you're just installing SuperSU, don't blindly follow this, especially don't wipe the phone.

Comment: Wait, SuperSU isn't a ROM?

Comment: @MrAndroidBoss No, it's an app that grants root access to other applications, but thanks anyway for making me sure I can do it without adb.

Answer (score 1):

With my experience I've learnt the side-load feature from TWRP is pretty finicky. I've only managed to get it working once and I had to do a lot of downgrading. I would load the file onto an SD card or USB and use an OTG cable (what I usually use) then flash it directly from the recovery. You can also flash things like [CF-Auto-Root](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/) and load it while in downloading mode with [Odin](http://androidcentral.us/2013/11/download-odin/) with tends to be a little less hassle free but confusing if you've never used Odin before

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes I will rather use good old flash via TWRP method